# Understanding the content in value attribute?

Tags: php

```
$userId = $_POST["userId"]
print <input type="hidden" name="userId" value='".$userId."'/>;
```

I can't understand what is inserted into the attribute value here and why here `dot`$userId`dot` actually does? I know that single `dot` operator is used for concatenation then why is here author used two?

Comment: It's not complete code. That syntax is used to insert php variables into HTML when php is already echoing the HTML string

Comment: of course this is not a complete code i want to understand only the conent of attribute value

Comment: dot is the concatenation character so it is inserting the content of `$userid` into the `value` attribute like `value="Admin"`. Except it looks like you have muddled up the single and double quotes.

Comment: what is the purpose of using two dot operaters here.

Comment: Concatenation. HTML to php variable, then back to HTML.

Comment: i would appeciate if u could debrief it a little bit i'm new to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your example has syntax errors. Should be:

```
$userId = $_POST["userId"];
print '<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="'.$userId.'" />';
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Basic Explanation:**

If `$userId = 123` (ie. `$_POST['userId'] = 123`), all that it's saying is add all the parts together using the `.`:

```
/* Piece 1->*/ '<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="'
```

**PLUS ( . ):**

```
/*Piece 2->*/ 123
```

**PLUS ( . ):**

```
/* Piece 3->*/ '" />'
```

**Would print to the browser:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="123" />
```

See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php